# is it possible to copy a datasets column into a grids columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dataset

is it possible to copy a datasets column into a grids columns

when i do this

```
GridView grid = new GridView();
Page.Controls.Add(grid); 
grid.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
grid.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;   
grid.DataBind();
```

only the items/rows of the dataset gets copied not the columns. How can i copy the columns?

The AutoGenerateColumns property does not work

Comment: Why you use `ds.Tables[0].DefaultView` as DataSource? Try `ds.Tables[0]`. To be clear, you are missing the header of the GridView?

Comment: yes the column property in the grid have a length of 0 columns. why does the columns not get added?

Comment: It's always empty when you use `AutoGenerateColumns`, but it should be visible anyway